# Pivot table using flat table structure in SQL Server without aggregation

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot

I have a flat table structure which I've turned into a column based table. I'm struggling with getting the rowId from my raw data to appear in my column based table. Any help greatly appreciated.

Raw data in table derived from three different tables:

```
| rowId            |columnName       |ColumnValue  |
| ---------------- |:---------------:| -----------:|
| 1                |itemNo           |1            |
| 1                |itemName         |Polo Shirt   |
| 1                |itemDescription  |Green        |
| 1                |price1           |4.2          |
| 1                |price2           |5.3          |
| 1                |price3           |7.5          |
| 1                |displayOrder     |1            |
| 1                |rowId            |[NULL]       |
| 2                |itemNo           |12           |
| 2                |itemName         |Digital Watch|
| 2                |itemDescription  |Red Watch    |
| 2                |price1           |4.0          |
| 2                |price2           |2.0          |
| 2                |price3           |1.5          |
| 2                |displayOrder     |3            |
| 2                |rowId            |[NULL]       |
```

SQL using pivot to give me the column structure:

```
select [displayOrder],[itemDescription],[itemName],[itemNo],[price1],[price2],[price3],[rowId]
 from 
(
SELECT  [columnName], [columnValue] , row_number() over(partition by c.columnName order by cv.rowId) as rn
FROM  tblFlatTable AS t
JOIN tblFlatColumns c
ON t.flatTableId = c.flatTableId
JOIN tblFlatColumnValues cv
ON cv.flatColumnId = c.flatColumnId
WHERE (t.flatTableId = 1) AND (t.isActive = 1) 
AND (c.isActive = 1) AND (cv.isActive = 1)
) as S
Pivot
(
    MIN([columnValue])
    FOR columnName IN ([displayOrder],[itemDescription],[itemName],[itemNo],[price1],[price2],[price3],[rowId])
) as P
```

Result:

```
|displayOrder|itemDescription|itemName      |price1|price2|price3|rowId |
| ---------- |:-------------:|:------------:|:----:|:----:|:----:|-----:|
|1           |Green          |Polo Shirt    |4.2   |5.3    |7.5  |[NULL]|
|3           |Red watch      |Digital Watch |4.0   |2.0    |1.5  |[NULL]|
```

I understand why I'm getting the NULL value for rowId. What I'm stuck on and I'm not sure if it's possible to do as I've looked an many example and none seem to do this, that is to pull the value for rowId from the raw data and add it to my structure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks obvious now!

I'm now not including rowId as part of my flat structure.

```
| rowId            |columnName       |ColumnValue  |
| ---------------- |:---------------:| -----------:|
| 1                |itemNo           |1            |
| 1                |itemName         |Polo Shirt   |
| 1                |itemDescription  |Green        |
| 1                |price1           |4.2          |
| 1                |price2           |5.3          |
| 1                |price3           |7.5          |
| 1                |displayOrder     |1            |
| 2                |itemNo           |12           |
| 2                |itemName         |Digital Watch|
| 2                |itemDescription  |Red Watch    |
| 2                |price1           |4.0          |
| 2                |price2           |2.0          |
| 2                |price3           |1.5          |
| 2                |displayOrder     |3            |
```

I've updated the SQL, you can see I'm pulling in the rowId from tblFlatColumnValues

```
select [rowId],[displayOrder],[itemDescription],[itemName],[itemNo],[price1],[price2],[price3]
 from 
(
SELECT  cv.rowId, [columnName], [columnValue] , row_number() over(partition by c.columnName order by cv.rowId) as rn
FROM  tblFlatTable AS t
JOIN tblFlatColumns c
ON t.flatTableId = c.flatTableId
JOIN tblFlatColumnValues cv
ON cv.flatColumnId = c.flatColumnId
WHERE (t.flatTableId = 1) AND (t.isActive = 1) 
AND (c.isActive = 1) AND (cv.isActive = 1)
) as S
Pivot
(
    MIN([columnValue])
    FOR columnName IN ([displayOrder],[itemDescription],[itemName],[itemNo],[price1],[price2],[price3])
) as P
```